# How do I add a specific page to breadcrumbs?

Tags: woocommerce, breadcrumbs

How do I add a specific page to breadcrumbs?

Example: I have a category of Chairs, in the crumbs Goes: Home > Chairs, I want my Page to be in certain categories, example: Home - Page1 - Chairs, Tables, etc

Is it possible? The fact is that in our menu there is a content page and then there are links to categories, I would like to link them to the page with crumbs